# K-th elemnt of list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'M a beginner in haskell, and trying to implement a function which returns the k-th element of a list without using the prelude `!!` built-in.

```
kth_i [] _ _ = -1
kth_i (x:xs) i k = if i == k then x else kth_i xs (i + 1) k
kth xs k = kth_i xs 0 k
```

This code works, but is too verbose. I'd like to use just one function.

Edit: I ended up with:

```
let kth (x:xs) k = if k == 0 then x else if k < 0 then error "out of bounds" else  kth xs (k - 1); kth [] _ = error "out of bounds"
```

As per @Carsten's suggestion.

Comment: well you count up from 0 to k ... what if you count down from k to 0 instead? Maybe you can get rid of `i`?

Comment: btw: the first line will force your result type into `Num a` which is not necessary - `(!!)` is partial and will fail if the list is empty - so maybe yours should do as well - you can use `undefined` or `error  "empty list"` instead of `-1` on the right hand side there or just remove the case completely if you like! Also you should think about nasty users who probably would ask you for `kth xs (-1)` - maybe this should be an error instead of an never-returning call as well?

Comment: Thanks! `let kth (x:xs) k = if k == 0 then x else kth xs (k - 1); kth [] _ = -1` Now I just need to handle errors

Comment: Now I have `let kth (x:xs) k = if k == 0 then x else if k < 0 then error "out of bounds" else  kth xs (k - 1); kth [] _ = error "out of bounds"`, which works for positive indices, but `kth [0..5] -1` returns:
`Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> t)`

Comment: you have to input it with `kth [0..5] (-1)`

Comment: also please edit your question instead of putting the code inside comments - maybe it's a problem with your indentation which we cannot see

Comment: `kth [0..5] (-1)` works, thanks!

Comment: @Carsten You can write an answer, and I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you found your solution but allow me to make it a bit nicer for you:

```
kth :: [a] -> Integer -> a
kth (x:xs) i
   | i < 0  = error "out of bounds"
   | i == 0 = x
   | i > 0  = kth xs (i-1)
kth [] _    = error "empty list"
```

this uses [*guards*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) instead of the `if`s - so if you did not see those before you should probably follow the link and read the wiki

Comment: Why is the type declaration necessary, isn't it inferred by the compiler?

Comment: yes it is (indeed the compiler would make it even more generic by getting rid of the `Integer`) - but it's good advice to add signatures to the top-level definitions - the compiler will even warn you if you don't - it will help you often with type errors (if you do something wrong) and it's valuable documentation ;)

Comment: @dimid, it turns out that the inferred signature will be *too general* in a sense--it will allow you to use numeric types like `Double` and `Rational` that will lead to weird behavior. It's best to constrain it a bit. Typically, the "generic" version of this function would be given the signature `kth :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> a`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** Here is the solution that uses pattern matching. You can also look at the implementation of the Haskell (!!) functions which is quite similar to this code : [!!](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#%21%21)

```
nth::[a]->Int->a
nth [] _ = error "out of bounds"
nth (x:xs) 0 = x
nth (x:xs) n = nth xs (n-1)
```

Comment: I think the question was how to get rid of `kth_i` which is a second function but yes of course this works...

Comment: You don't want to limit yourself to lists of ints.

Comment: @Carsten thanks! I thought OP is talking about not using pattern matching. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

A simple definition, assuming the list *has* at least `k + 1` items:

```
kth :: Integer -> [a] -> a
kth k = head . drop k
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else mentioned this, I figure I should: partial functions (ones that sometimes give rise to error messages or infinite loops) are typically discouraged in Haskell. We tend to prefer to deal with total functions, expressing failure using types like `Maybe` and `Either`. Even when we deal with partial functions, we tend to try to limit hard-to-handle errors. The most extreme version might be something like this:

```
data Kth a = NegativeIndex | ShortList | Kth a

kth :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> Kth a
kth _ k | k < 0 = NegativeIndex
kth [] _ = ShortList
kth (x : _) 0 = Kth x
kth (_ : xs) k = kth xs (k - 1)
```

This gives very informative results, but it's pretty awkward to use. If you're confident the index given will never be negative, you can use this one instead:

```
kth :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> Maybe a
kth _ k | k < 0 = error "Negative index"
kth [] _ = Nothing
kth (x : _) 0 = Just x
kth (_ : xs) k = kth xs (k - 1)
```

Note that if you specialize this version to the `Natural` type from `Numeric.Natural` (available in recent versions of GHC), then you can leave out the `< 0` test because natural numbers really *can't* be negative!

Sticking to the polymorphic code for now, you can see that there's a minor inefficiency: `kth` will check for `k < 0` on every recursive call, even though it's only possible for that to happen on the first one. You can avoid that by using a helper function:

```
kth :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> Maybe a
kth xs k | k < 0 = error "Negative index"
         | otherwise = kth' xs k
  where
    kth' [] _ = Nothing
    kth' (x : _) 0 = Just x
    kth' (_ : xs) k = kth' xs (k - 1)
```

Once we've gone this far, we might as well have a bit more fun. The helper function matches the `foldr` "design pattern", so we can write it like this:

```
kth' xs = foldr go (const Nothing) xs where
  go x _ 0 = Just x
  go _ r i = r (i - 1)
```

Inlining this version of `kth'`, we get

```
kth xs k | k < 0 = error "Negative index"
         | otherwise = foldr go (const Nothing) xs k
  where
    go x _ 0 = Just x
    go _ r i = r (i - 1)
```

For optimization purposes, it's probably best to replace `(const Nothing)` with `` (`seq` Nothing) ``, and to replace `r (i - 1)` with `r $! i - 1`, but it's probably not a good idea to go into the full details of why just now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! (wish I could upvote twice :)
If I understood correctly, all versions in your answer are partial functions. If so, what would the total function look like? Also, why is the first version 'awkward to use'?

Comment: @dimid, the first is total. The second and third could be made total by replacing `error ...` with `Nothing`, but then `Nothing` would have two potential meanings.

Comment: @dimid, there are a lot more tools for `Maybe` than that weird type. You could fix that, I suppose, by declaring `data BadNth = NegativeIx | TooShort` and then using `Either BadNth a`.